# How to display buttons based on user login in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing a Education App. I have a login screen. Here we have used php to check for valid user. If he his a valid user then he can go to Other Screen.Here I need to display buttons like people,contact us,news,events and so on... depends the user.

I Mean I need to display buttons depending on the user. For example if student is logged in then I need to display people, news,events. If a person from administration logged in then I need to display some  more buttons like Admissions, Fees...

Comment: Don't indent paragraphs: a) no one does that any more; b) it turns them into "code".

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the buttons in the `xib` and then check the `type of the user logged in` from the php.

And From the type of user, you can `show / hide` those `buttons`.

You can also use another way as to `create the buttons dynamically (programatically)` as per php response for the user type.

`For example,` if the user type returned from the php is student then show / hide or create buttons like people, news,events and If user type  returned from the php is administration then show / hide or create buttons like like Admissions, Fees.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a check on user, if user is student or administrator then show the appropriate buttons by doing :

`button.hidden = FALSE;` or `button.hidden= TRUE;`

P.S you can place this check in your view (class) under `viewDidLoad` which you want to show after user logged in.

Let me know if you need further help!

Happy Coding!!

Comment: ok,are you able to check for student or admin (who is signing in) ?

Answer (score 0):

php service will be response back as valid user and their roles like student, administrator..right..!
So based on the response, have to add your functionality like below

```
switch (role)
    {
        case student:
        {
            // student view contains display people,news,events buttons
            // add student view as subView
            break;
        }
        case administrator:
        {
            // admin view contains display people,news,events buttons and more buton
            // add admin view as subView
            break;
        }
   }
```

design the student view and admin view with specific buttons in xib or programmatically based on your need and add them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all buttons. And then depending on user type you need to hide few buttons or show all buttons. You just need to check for user type.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can do like this, during registration process provide user with one column "type" along with username,password, gender.. and ask him to enter/select whether he is of type student or admin. These details i.e., user details will store in database .Basically you will write query in the php file to get/check for valid user. along with this get type of user also whether student/ admin. After getting results through query check for condition like if results equal to student then push response like student found else send response like admin found. Actually after clicking login button u will get these response .Based on this response that is if student found navigate to students page/provide students details else navigate to admin page .

hope it will helps u .. if u have any doubts please let me know..